# PHPExcel, Save string without changes

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to save a multidimensional array data in a xls file

This is my code:

```
    $arr = array(
        array("01", "02", "03"),
        array("04", "05", "06"),
    );


    // include PHPExcel library

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($arr);

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save("file.xls");
```

My problem is that starting nulls are removed in my xls file. For example is saved not as `01`, but as `1`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: check the format of the cell in excel. maybe it is only a display issue. excel likes it to convert the format of a cell fitted to its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a string with a numeric value to retain leading zeroes, then you have two choices:
Write it as a string using
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')
        ->setValueExplicit(
            '01', 
            PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING
        );
(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING is the default, so you don't actually have to specify that argument)

or allow it to be written as a number, and then set a format mask to display it with leading zeroes

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode("00");
```

**EDIT**

You can apply a style to a range of cells, not just to individual cells

```
$arr = array(
    array("01", "02", "03"),
    array("04", "05", "06"),
);

// include PHPExcel library
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($arr);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C2')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode("00");
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a solution on the forum:
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/31240

Comment: It's also in the documentation - I really wish people would look there before posting questions

Comment: @MarkBaker: Then there wouldn`t be stackoverflow :P :))

Comment: Sorry @KA_lin - pet peeve. People complain that there's no documentation; I spend months writing documentation; people still ask all the questions that are answered in that documentation; I wonder why I wasted months writing it

Comment: @MarkBaker: Oh sorry now I saw what you do :) Thank  you for your work, you have saved me allot of time

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the row's attribute like this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A0')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("@");
```

but i don't know what format you need ,just look for the mannul